# Singleton HttpClient for android application

Tags: java, android, http, httprequest

Hello I am making an android application where I need to call the Web API for which I can use the libraries also like `volley` etc but I am not looking for that.

To do my task I am making `HttpClient` to singleton so that use same `httpClient` for each http call. I never close the connection once http request is completed because if I close the `httpClient` then I have to get another instance of it.

CustomHttpClient.java

```
private static HttpClient httpClient;

public static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if(httpClient == null) {
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
    return httpClient;
}
```

NetworkHelper.java

```
public static InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
    InputStream content = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = CustomHttpClient.getHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        content = response.getEntity().getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.("Demo", "Network exception", e);
    }
    return content;
}
```

Can you please help me is it good practice to call http request like so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [apache](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html) it is recommended to have a single instance of HttpClient per communication component or even per application.

But you need to keep in mind before implementing such a Singleton HttpClient.

1. Make sure you are using a Thread to do all your downloading in the background and don't use the UI Thread.
2. Maintain a queue for all the download requests. All these requests need to be queued and run one after the other.
3. In case you switch an Activity before the HttpClient queue is clear, the queue should be cleared so that it does not start the loading of your components of the new activity.
4. Close the client when everything finished.

Comment: If I close the client, wont it create any issue next time to call the web API using closed http client status because next time it would return same http client as per my code?

Comment: Handle that technically on your code. Close only when you finish up everything. like for ex. on activity destroy.

Comment: Handle that technically on your code ?? I got you I should close it but my question is "wont it create any issue next time to call the web API using closed http client status because next time it would return same http client as per my code?"

Comment: It shouldn't, because if have created the client and reference it on your entry point activity and used that in other activities (as it is singleton) then close it when your app closes or entry point activity destroys it will clear the previous references and the instance will be garbage collected. Make sure to use onDestroy(). otherwise it will create problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is alerady implemented in the AndroidHttpClient class. I have used it, and it works really good. You can use it the same way you use `HttpClient`. Just make shure you use the `newInstance` method.

AndroidHttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(null);

To prevent creating many instances of the `InputStream content = null;` you can make it like some private variable of the class where you implemented `getInputStreamFromUrl` method, change the return type to the object where you parse your response into, and just close the InputStream, you dont need to initialize over and over again. You can make somehting like this:

```
private static InputStream content = null;
private AndroidHttpClient httpclient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(null);

public static YourType getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {

    try {
        YourType yourCustomType = new YourType();           
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        content = response.getEntity().getContent();

        //Parse response to YourType object here

        content.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.("Demo", "Network exception", e);
    }
    return yourCustomType;
}
```

Comment: Thanks If I close the client, wont it create any issue next time to call the web API using closed http client status because next time it would return same http client as per my code?

Comment: You can review the documentation and find the newInstance method.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html

Returns
AndroidHttpClient for you to use for all your requests.

Comment: I updated the answer again with your sub-question. It should not be an issue if you re-use it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad solution but it's not good too. Here is the reasons

1) Official recomendation:

> Generally it is recommended to have a single instance of HttpClient per communication component or even per application

2) `AndroidHttpClient` is the same what you are doing, but it implemented not as a singleton.

3) You can see in [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.java#AndroidHttpClient.finalize%28%29) of `AndroidHttpClient` if connection would not be closed `finalize` method says that it's very bad

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    super.finalize();
    if (mLeakedException != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Leak found", mLeakedException);
        mLeakedException = null;
    }
}
```

**Update**

I guess I would use it like below

```
public static InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
    InputStream content = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        content = response.getEntity().getContent();
        httpclient.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.("Demo", "Network exception", e);
    }
    return content;
}
```

Comment: If I close the client, wont it create any issue next time to call the web API using closed http client status because next time it would return same http client as per my code? –

Comment: It would be. Because of that you have to use new instance of client for every request.

Comment: OK but it is not good practice to use new instance of client for every request as you said "Generally it is recommended to have a single instance of HttpClient per communication component or even per application", then How I can handle this situation using my code to have single http client and close it and should work for next http calls also ?

Comment: and I saw your code which you shared in the answer that you also did not close the http client. Any reason ? or will it close automatically ?

Comment: To be completely sure, I would advise you to look at the source code of popular applications or libraries.

Comment: I'm not talking about using, I'm talking about See how others do it.